# How to skip attributes when converting an XML file into a Dataset displayed with DataGridView

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-dataset

As stated in my question,

i have a XML file that outputs as follows:

```
<cme Type="Object" Class="cme">
<sId Type="String">1</sId>
<conc Type="Double">18,6511073619</conc>
  </cme>
<cme Type="Object" Class="cme">
<sId Type="String">2</sId>
<conc Type="Double">18,3226889524</conc>
</cme>
<cme Type="Object" Class="cme">
<sId Type="String">3</sId>
<conc Type="Double">4,7920021996</conc>
</cme>....
```

I created a new Form in Visual Studio and there added the following code:

```
        cmDataSet.ReadXml(filePath,XmlReadMode.InferSchema);
        cmDataGrid.DataSource = cmDataSet;
        cmDataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        cmDataGrid.DataMember = "cme"; <-- Parent Node
```

But when the form is displayed, while the number of rows matches the count,
the cells are filled with the values of the attributes, and NOT the real values, in this way:

```
Object  cme
Object  cme
Object  cme
Object  cme
```

How do I skip the attributes from being evaluated to display the real values only?

Comment: Can you try `InferTypedSchema` instead of `InferSchema`?

Comment: Did it, the output didn't change a bit.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to create xsd schema for your xml file. And add `cmDataSet.ReadXmlSchema` call to code:

```
cmDataSet.ReadXmlSchema(xsdFilePath);
cmDataSet.ReadXml(filePath, XmlReadMode.InferSchema);
cmDataGrid.DataSource = cmDataSet;
cmDataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
cmDataGrid.DataMember = "cme"; <-- Parent Node
```

You need schema, because currently dataset will hold 3 DataTables: `cme`, `sId` and `conc`. Which is not what you are looking for.

Actually, if xml file have no schema it is as good and easy to work with as with an "angle bracket separated text".

Another approach is to use LINQ to XML and construct anonymous object (or create strongly typed object and map to it) that will represent your data grid row:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(filePath);
var rows = doc.Root.Elements("cme")
.Select(e => new
{
    cId = e.Element("sId").Value,
    conc = e.Element("conc").Value
});

cmDataGrid.DataSource = rows.ToList();
cmDataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
```

Using LINQ projections is a quick and easy way to display data but you can lose a lot of time during implementation of the "add/update/edit row" scenarios.

Comment: This sounds a little complicated though, since I'll have to edit the schema to remove cme.Shouldn't it be possible to write some code to select only the data I want?

Comment: @user1776401 If you need only to display data you can use LINQ to XML to construct a list of objects and then bind them to data grid. See my updated answer.